# Wrapping a select box into a custom element

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, custom-element, lit-element

I want to build a html custom element which should behave nearly identical to the native `<select>` element but in addition, it also has to call a certain update function each time an attribute or a child node changes. (back story: This is a necessary step for using the [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) element inside the elm framework. See also [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61572939/3066306).)

Using the LitElement framework, I was able to build a working custom element (called `<lit-select>`) similar to the description above. But unfortunately, I was not able to make it accept html `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements as childs. Instead, the user has to pass the option list to a certain attribute as a json encoded string.

That is, istead of calling

```html
<lit-select>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</lit-select>
```

the user has to call

```html
<lit-select items='["foo", "bar"]'></lit-select>
```

In which way I have to change my definition of `<lit-select>` to make the first call possible? I am aware of the `<slot>` element but unfortunately, this element is not allowed inside `<select>`, so the browser simply deletes it.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Update 1**

There are actually some restrictions making the problem more challenging than I thought at first:

- I have to avoid shadow DOM. This is because my custom element is getting styled/enhanced by bootstrap (and bootstrap-select) css/js which only look into the ordinary DOM. As I just learned, this rules out `slot` elements, since these are shadow DOM specific.
- My custom element has to be fully responsive to changes (adding/removing child notes, changing attributes). This is because I plan to use the element inside a virtual DOM (elm in my case but it should also work with react).

---

**Appendix**

My definition of `<lit-select>`:

```js
import { LitElement, html, customElement, property } from 'lit-element';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-select';

@customElement('lit-select')
export class LitSelect extends LitElement {

    @property({ type : Array }) items = []

    updated() {
        $(this).find(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
    }

    createRenderRoot() {
        return this;
    }

    private renderItem(item: string) {
        return html`
            <option>
                ${item}
            </option>
        `;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search = "true">
                ${this.items.map(item => this.renderItem(item))}
            </select>
        `;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with a **Native W3C standard Custom Element**

All you have to do is **move** some `<option>` elements.

```html
<template id=MY-SELECT>
  <h3>My Never Todo List</h3>
  <select multiple></select>
</template>

<my-select name="NTD">
  <option>Grow up</option>
  <option>Learn React</option>
  <option>Use Lit</option>
  <option>Forget W3C Custom Elements API</option>
</my-select>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-select", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["name"]; //use one to trigger attributeChangedCallback
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log('connected');
      //clone template
      this.append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
      //MOVE options inside SELECT:
      this.querySelector('select').append(...this.querySelectorAll('option'));
    }
    attributeChangedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => this.updated(...arguments))// execute after Event Loop is done
    }
    updated(name,oldValue,newValue){
      console.log('updated',name,oldValue,newValue);
    }
  })

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast response! One reason for using LitElement is that it provides the "updated" callback, which is exactly the right place for invoking the refresh function I need. Unfortunately, "connectedCallback" is invoked too early (and only once!). Also, I cannot use shadow root because my element will be changed by bootstrap functions which do not (simply) work inside shadow roots.

Comment: I have updated the code. No shadowDOM and an update method. ``connectedCallback`` isn't invoked too early... Your code wants to do something before the Event Loop is done creating those elements. So delay your code. Lit also waits for elements to be actually there.

Comment: Thanks again, your approach looks very promising! I will try it soon. Actually, I already have tried "setTimeout" inside "connectedCallback" and declined that idea, because this leads to race conditions. For example (on my hardware), waiting 1ms is not sufficient. Waiting 3ms sometimes suffices and sometimes does not. The problem is, I have to wait for rendering completion. This is not the same thing as waiting for the event loop being cleared.

Comment: It all depends what you doing with DOM elements. You can't do something with DOM elements if they are not there (yet) A 0 ms Settimeout should be enough in a connectedCallback... unless you are doing async stuff with those Bootstrap thingies.. but don't  incorporate Elements then.. first make it work with standard JS code. If you don't you are stacking technologies making it more and more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```js
import {LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';


export class GraniteSelect extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
    return {
      options: {
        type: Object,
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.options =  [];
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();

    this.observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        mutation.removedNodes.forEach((node) => {
          if (node.nodeName === 'OPTION' ) {
            this.options = [ ...this.options, node ];
           console.log(`options - ${this.options}`);
           console.dir(this.options);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    this.observer.observe(this, {
        childList: true,
    });
  }

  firstUpdate() {
    this.observer.disconnect();
  }

  createRenderRoot() {
  /**
   * Render template without shadow DOM. Note that shadow DOM features like 
   * encapsulated CSS and slots are unavailable.
   */
    return this;
  }


  render() {
    console.log('Rendering', this.options);
    return html`
      <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search = "true">
          ${this.options}
      </select>
    `;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('granite-select', GraniteSelect);
```

It uses light-dom (the `createShadowRoot` part), and it puts all the options children of your element inside the `select`. The non-options children are simply ignored, but you could do anything with them.

You can see a full example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-14dcae

What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Looks interesting! However, since you are closing the observer after first update, the node won't change if somebody (e.g. the virtual dom) addes or deletes child notes. Of course we could adapt the observer to react properly to all kind of dom operations, but this seems way to complicated for me...

Comment: Yes, in that case you shouldn't close the observer, and use it synchronize the children with the options properties at every mutation. It's more complicated, indeed, but I am not sure you can do simpler in this case